# Let's blacklist the [graph] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging, tag-blacklist

The [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) tag is supposed to be for questions about the graphs of functions.  But it is very commonly misapplied to questions that are about the graphs of graph theory.  These questions are supposed to have the [graph-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) tag instead.  Many don't.

Many questions have both tags.  There are between 50 and 100 questions tagged with both graph and graph-theory, and I would be surprised if both tags were appropriate for even one of these.

The [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) tag is usually wrong.  I suggested in the "tagging" chat that we:

1. Eliminate [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph)
2. Replace it with something less ambiguous: perhaps [function-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-graph), or perhaps just eliminate it

   - (My current favorite suggestion is that we replace it with [graphing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphing).)
3. Blacklist it to prevent further confusion

I suggested this in the "tagging" chat.
Martin Sleziak, the person who seems to have given the most thought to tagging issues, replied:

> It is good that you have mentioned this problem. I've retagged a few questions (but there is a lot of them remaining.) I've also added a comment template [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587).
>   If you think that the [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) tag should be blacklisted, you should probably start a meta thread. Blacklisting a tag is a big decision, so the community should know about it and it would be good if some consensus could be achieved.

I thought about it some more, and here we are.  There are a few hundred questions tagged with [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph), so it would not  be an insurmountable task to eliminate them manually.  Around one-sixth of these also have [graph-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), and we might decide, as a first step, to mechanically remove [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) from each of those; this would be correct in the great majority of cases.

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 I am not sure we need a replacement. In the most common formalization of functions in set theory, the graph of a function is exactly the function. One can certainly debate this, but the concept doesn't strike me as sufficiently unique. Questions on whether some graph of a function is measurable or how one should scale the graph of $x^3$ when plotting are sufficiently different, that nobody will be going to favorite the tag (I guess).

Comment: Tag-wiki for [tag:functions] currently says: *Elementary questions about functions, notation, properties, and operations such as function composition.* If this is the kind for questions we want to have in this tag, it is more-or-less subset of [tag:elementary-set-theory] and [tag:discrete-mathematics]. Questions concerning graph of functions more usually appear in (pre)calculus. So I think it's better to have a separate [tag:graph] tag than simply transferring all questions to [tag:functions]. The content of this tag wiki was discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/)

Comment: Perhaps I should mentioned that we have discussed [whether functions tag is really needed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/715/should-we-have-a-functions-tag). But now that tag has about 2k questions (and 36 followers), so I don't think it's probable that it is going to be removed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: my concern would be that someone asking a question about drawing a graph would never type "set" or "discrete" into the tag box.

Comment: @BenMillwood The suggested replacement by (function-graph) tag would solve this. (Even in the case if we decide that the tags (function-graph) and (functions) should be syonyms.)

Comment: I think [tag:graphing] would be a better replacement for [tag:graph] than [tag:function-graph] would be.  People trying to draw the graph of function might be well-served by the tag [tag:graphing]. They would be as likely to tag their question with [tag:graphing] as they would have with [tag:graph]. People with graph theory questions would be unlikely to use [tag:graphing] for graph theory.

Comment: The name (graphing) would not cover questions such as: *Is graph of a continuous function always a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R^2$?*, *How can I say from the graph whether $f$ is injective?*, *Does connected graph implies continuity?* etc. Do we want to exclude this type of questions from the replacement for (graph)? (The tag-excerpt we have in the moment suggests that (graph) is for any question concerning graphs of functions.)

Comment: I just want to note the obvious and say that if we are to remove it, we should make our edits in a somewhat controlled way--we don't want to flood the front page... `:)`

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised. I half expected graphs of functions to be called plots nowadays, because that's what some CAS call them. Similarly, aren't *graphing* and *plotting* synonyms? I may be wrong, as English is not my first language, but I think in my use the two words are interchangable :-/

Comment: @Martin: I would exclude those from the replacement for (graph); they belong in (general-topology), and the first one probably belongs in (real-analysis) as well, at least as the tag is actually used.

Comment: @Brian I am ok with excluding such questions, if it is prevalent opinion. But it should be reflected in tag-wiki/tag-excerpt. So perhaps instead of "Questions regarding graphs of functions." the tag-excerpt should read "Questions regarding drawing graphs of functions."\\A recent example where the tag was used in broader sense: [Does Closed Graph imply Closed Range](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326902/does-closed-graph-imply-closed-range).

Comment: @Jyrki At least we can say for sure that the tag [tag:plot] is one of the [synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph/synonyms) for the tag [tag:graph]. (I should leave the language questions for native speakers.)

Comment: @anorton: actually, while the discussion is taking place _now_ we can at the very least retag all the (graph-theory) questions slowly slowly. Then depending on the outcome of the [discussion here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/what-should-be-in-the-tag-graph) the remainder may be dealt with by a simple tag-rename by a moderator.

Comment: Question: why do you guys wrap tag names in [brackets], when they're normally displayed between (parentheses)?

Comment: Perhaps *sketching* would be an appropriate replacement?

Comment: Why not make it as clear as possible and just go with (graphing-functions)?

Comment: I've added some suggestions for the new name as CW-answers, so that the users can show their opinion by voting. If you think some other possibilities should be added, please, do so.

Comment: [Plotting] and [function-graph] bother me slightly as if a first-timer-er were to ask a question on plotting graphs then they would start by typing "graph" into the tag bar. [plotting] or [function-graph] would need to be one of the options - would they appear though?

Comment: @user1729 When you star typing, the tags which contain the characters you type or which have synonyms containing those characters appear as suggestions. (I think it's reasonable to choose several of the suggested replacements and make them synonyms of the main one.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Okay,thanks, then I hold the opinion that [plotting] should only be allowed if it has a synonym involving the word "graph" (and I prefer [plotting] to [graphing]).

Comment: This question is now approximately one month old and it received a lot of upvotes. Perhaps it is already time to do the suggested blacklisting. I'm going to flag the question for moderators' attention, so that they can decide what has to be done next.

Comment: @Martin: saw your flag. We would need to rename the tag before we black list it (I think). It looks like from the votes below the new name is (graphing-functions); I don't have a problem with that. But before we do the mass rename, we should find the ones that don't fit per your own comment http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag#comment29834_8729 and manually rename them. The only way to do that is to go through the list slowly over the next few days.

Comment: Once the manual retags are done, ping me again (or any other mod) and we can rename the tag to (graphing-functions), set up the appropriate synonyms, and request the blacklist for (graph).

Comment: @WillieWong I've retagged the questions mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8985/). Please, have a look [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8889717#8889717) for a more detailed comment. (And, if something has to be done before the mass-renaming and blacklisting, let me know there or here.)

Answer (score 17):

Tag named (graphing-functions) would be a good replacement for [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph).
Please upvote/downvote this answer to show your opinion on this.

Answer (score 15):

Tag named (graphing) would be a good replacement for [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph).
Please upvote/downvote this answer to show your opinion on this.

Answer (score 10):

I think the following proposal addresses all points:

Blacklist the tag [graph]. Put an entry in the tag-wiki indicating to consider either [graph-theory] or [graphing].

Make [plot] and [plotting] into synonyms for [graphing].

If people want it, also add [function-graph] to cover questions like [this one Martin Sleziak found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326902) which ask about the graph of a function in a non-visual manner. Having scanned through the entire [graph] tag, I only found this one question where I would use this tag, so I don't think it is necessary, but I have no strong objection to it.

I like [graphing] as a tag because I think it is the term an unsophisticated poster would use for this topic, and it is a topic that attracts a lot of basic questions.

Comment: *Graphing*, as a verb, seems to be North American teacher-ese coming mainly from algebra and calculus textbooks (by which I mean the ones aimed for the average student in high school and college) and calculator manufacturers.  It is jargon bloat relative to the pre-existing words "drawing" and "graph". In this respect I would rather it be disfavored.  For the computer and statistical plotting questions *graphics* would be more precise.

Comment: *Put an entry in the tag-wiki indicating to consider...* If I'm not mistaken, after blacklisting, the tag will be out of the system completely, so there will be no tag-wiki for (graph).

Comment: @zyx: *Graphing* isn’t used as a verb. It’s used as a gerund (verbal noun), as in ‘*graphing* these functions is hard’, and as an adjective, as in ‘a graphing calculator’ and ‘these graphing problems are hard’. If you meant the transitive verb *to graph*, it’s standard and has been around since at least 1898. *Graphics* would be a very poor choice: it is very strongly associated with computer graphics and not at all with graphing functions. At least in the U.S. David’s last paragraph is spot-on.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes the gerund is what I meant. With the 5 minute edit window, 7 minute mistakes are here for posterity.  I have experienced only "draw the graph of $f$" or "the graph of $f$ has (property)" in lectures to mathematically mature audiences and in non-introductory non-North American books. *Graphics* is proposed only for the computer and statistical plotting questions, that seem to be a significant fraction of the questions with words "plot" and "plotting".  Evidently it is not the right word for questions about drawing $y = f(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

I have renamed (graph) to (graphing-functions), the [highest voted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8828/1543) of the suggested targets.

There are still some questions in [graphing-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphing-functions) that are not quite using the tag in this more restricted sense. Please help us retag them!

Also, we still need to come to a conclusion about how to tag question about graphs as the subset of $D\times R$ for $f:D\to R$.

*Edit:* The exact terms (graph) and (graphs) have now been blacklisted.

Answer (score 3):

Tag named (plotting) would be a good replacement for [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph).
Please upvote/downvote this answer to show your opinion on this.

Answer (score 1):

Tag named (function-graph) would be a good replacement for [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph).
Please upvote/downvote this answer to show your opinion on this.